# string indices must be integer

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to access a JSON object/dictionary in python however get the error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers if script['title'] ==
>   "IT":

and this is my code to try and access that particular key within the dictionary:

```
def CreateScript(scriptsToGenerate):
    start = time.clock()
    apiLocation = ""
    saveFile = ""
    for script in scriptsToGenerate:
        print script
        if script['title'] == "IT":
            time = script['timeInterval']
            baseItem = ""
```

and scriptsToGenerate is passed in using this which makes a HTTP request to my API

```
def GetScripts(urlParameters):
    result = requests.get(constURLString + "/" + str(urlParameters)).json()
    return [x for x in result if x != []]
```

and here is where I call CreateScript

```
def RunInThread(ID):
    startedProcesses = list()
    Scripts = []
    Scripts = GetScripts(ID)

    scriptList = ThreadChunk(Scripts, 2) 

    for item in scriptList: 
        proc = Process(target=CreateScript, args=(item))
        startedProcesses.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    #we must wait for the processes to finish before continuing
    for process in startedProcesses:
        process.join()
        print "finished"
```

which I pass this into CreateScript

Here is the output of my script object

```
{u'timeInterval': u'1800', u'title': u'IT', u'attribute' : 'hello'}
```

Comment: Please show the *exact* code you use to call `CreateScript`.

Comment: `script` is not what you think it is. The interpreter doesn't lie.

Comment: print your item before calling `Process(target=CreateScript, args=(item))` and see what is comming

Comment: You need to load the json object to slice it, do a `json.loads()` before `if script['title'] == "IT"`

Comment: @AdemÖztaş it is of <type 'dict'>

Comment: @ajsp can I do a json.loads() on the whole script and assign it to a variable and then use that?

Answer (score 1):

Facts:

- `scriptList` is a list of dictionaries (according to you)
- `for item in scriptList:` gets one dictionary at a time
- `proc = Process(target=CreateScript, args=(item))` passes a dictionary to the `CreateScript` function
- `def CreateScript(scriptsToGenerate):` receives a dictionary
- `for script in scriptsToGenerate:` iterates over the *keys* of the dictionary.
- `if script['title'] == "IT":` tries to access the `title` index of a dictionary key (a string).

So no, this won’t work. At some point, you iterate over a list. You probably want to pass a list of scripts to the `CreateScript` function, so you shouldn’t iterate over `scriptList`.

Answer (score 0):

John, what I meant was that you have a json object there, it will need to be treated as such. I think you mean can you do the following?

```
def CreateScript(scriptsToGenerate):
    #start = time.clock()
    apiLocation = ""
    saveFile = ""
    i = json.loads(scriptsToGenerate)
    if i['title'] == "IT":
        time = i['timeInterval']
        baseItem = ""

        print i['title'], i['timeInterval']

p = json.dumps({u'timeInterval': u'1800', u'title': u'IT', u'attribute' : 'hello'})

CreateScript(p)
```

Comment: The JSON is loaded as part of the `GetScripts` function by the requests library.

Comment: @poke right, I don't use the requests library, that's pretty handy, might use it in future.